# SQL Server: Return one match from left join (using month() function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join two tables together based on multiple criteria: policy number, transaction type, year of a date, month of a date

The majority of the policies will work fine with this code, but there are a few that will have multiple rows of data that would satisfy the join criteria, therefore returning duplicate rows for my select statement.

There is no best way to choose which one match to return (earliest date, first match, etc), so really I just care that the code returns only one row of data (no duplicates).

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated!

```
select
a.POLICY_NUMBER,
a.POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE,
a.POLICY_START_DATE,
b.COMMISSION_RATE,
from Table_1 as a
left join Table_2 as b
on
    a.POLICY_NUMBER = b.POLICY_NUMBER
    and a.POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE
    and year(a.POLICY_START_DATE) = year(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
    and month(a.POLICY_START_DATE) = month(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
```

**EDIT**

Sample Table_1

```
POLICY_NUMBER  POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE  POLICY_YEAR_START_DATE
1              REN                      1/1/2016
1              MTA                      15/1/2016
```

Sample Table_2

```
POLICY_NUMBER  TRANSACTION_TYPE  EFFECTIVE_DATE  COMMISSION_RATE
1              REN               1/1/2016        0.3
1              MTA               14/1/2016       0.1
1              MTA               16/1/2016       -0.1
```

So the original code would return this...

```
POLICY_NUMBER  POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE  POLICY_YEAR_START_DATE COMMISSION_RATE
1              REN                      1/1/2016               0.3
1              MTA                      15/1/2016              0.1
1              MTA                      15/1/2016              -0.1
```

Where I would like it just to return one of those rows for the MTA, whether it's the 0.1 commission rate or the -0.1 commission rate, I don't mind.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Probably a distinct will remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, without sample data and results.  Let me assume that the duplicates are coming from `table2`.  You can arbitrarily choose one using `row_number()`:

```
from Table_1 a left join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by POLICY_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_TYPE, year(EFFECTIVE_DATE), month(EFFECTIVE_DATE)
                                order by TRANSACTION_TYPE -- this will be an arbitrary ordering
                               ) as seqnum
      from Table_2 b
     ) b
     on a.POLICY_NUMBER = b.POLICY_NUMBER and
        a.POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE and
        year(a.POLICY_START_DATE) = year(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE) and
        month(a.POLICY_START_DATE) = month(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.POLICY_NUMBER,
       a.POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE,
       a.POLICY_START_DATE,
       MAX(b.COMMISSION_RATE)
from Table_1 as a
left join Table_2 as b
    on a.POLICY_NUMBER = b.POLICY_NUMBER and
       a.POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE and
       year(a.POLICY_START_DATE) = year(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE) and
       month(a.POLICY_START_DATE) = month(b.EFFECTIVE_DATE)

group by a.POLICY_NUMBER,
         a.POLICY_TRANSACTION_TYPE,
         a.POLICY_START_DATE
```